# Bootstrap - My mobile toggle button appears in all viewports?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been watching tutorials on creating a responsive navbar and one thing I am trying to create is a responsive menu button. I have created the button as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickmadd/LvhCh/4/

The HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default affix-top nav-links" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="media/img/nav-logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales Logo" class="img-rounded logo-nav navbar-brand" /></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Used Cars</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Get Finance</a>

            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Driven<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li> <a href "#">The Team</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href "#">Our Partners</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!--Drop Down End-->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Find Us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

The CSS

```
.navbar-toggle {
display: block;
}
.logo-nav {
height: 2.3em;
width: auto;
}
.brand {
font-size: 2em;
margin: 20px 0 25px;
}
.navbar-brand {
opacity: 0;
color: #ff0066;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-o-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
margin-left: 0px;
}
.navbar {
border-radius: 0px;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar- default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #DD3B4D;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu {
color: #fff;
background-color: #DD3B4D;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
color: #fff;
}
nav.affix {
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
nav.affix .navbar-brand {
opacity: 1;
height: 2.3em;
width: auto;
}
.navbar-header {
width: 0px;
-webkit-transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 1em 0 1em
}
nav.affix .navbar-header {
width: 8em;
-webkit-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.nav-links {
font: 600 15px/1.5'Arimo';
}
.navbar-nav > li:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid #475d88;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
color: #fff !important;
background-color: #DD3B4D !important;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
-o-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
nav.affix .navbar-brand {
display: inline-block;
}
```

The issue is that when it opens in the browser it is still there even in a large viewpoint. I need it to appear when it get's towards mobile size. I could go and do this with media queries but I'm sure that bootstrap is meant to do this for you?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are overriding the Bootstrap css with your own css, at the very top of your css you have:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
```

which tells ".navbar-toggle" to always show. Remove this and it will show/hide correctly. Also these [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) might be useful if you have any more trouble.

**Update**

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h2cL/1/) with correct syntax. The main issue was that you had `.nav-collapse` instead of `.navbar-collapse`.

Comment: I've just removed that in the jsfiddle and it's still loading with it open :?

http://jsfiddle.net/LvhCh/7/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the hidden class which is a large part of bootstrap's responsiveness on different viewport sizes. Check out this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bU8vAD4FMU)

Your button works fine when you make it hidden on large and medium viewports:

```
    <button class="navbar-toggle hidden-md hidden-lg" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
</button>
```

Read about the sizes and hiding [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). You can add that class to everything in bootstrap, so move it around if you want to hide more or less.

Comment: Thanks worked a treat! In the tutorials I didn't see anybody add that. Can I be cheeky and just ask how I stop the page loading with the mobile menu open? At the moment the toggle is open on mobile view, I will just play about with it for a while if not.

Comment: While this does work (kind of), it is not correct. This just hacks on some Bootstrap classes but it isn't actually making the Bootstrap nav system work so it doesn't really solve anything.